# Confusing prompts from cgdb "Start it from the beginning?"

Tags: gdb, cgdb

Running a multi-threaded app in cgdb (with gdb defaults in terms of scheduler-locking (off), non-stop (off), etc), and I'm getting these bizarre "unprompted" prompts, like so:

```
[New Thread 0x7ffff0bfb700 (LWP 16513)]                                                                                                                                                      [1964/1964]
[Thread 0x7ffff0bfb700 (LWP 16513) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffefbf9700 (LWP 16510) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff13fc700 (LWP 16512) exited]
Start it from the beginning? (y or n)
[New Thread 0x7fffe4d55700 (LWP 16623)]
[Thread 0x7fffe4d55700 (LWP 16623) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffe4d55700 (LWP 16624)]
[Thread 0x7fffe4d55700 (LWP 16624) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffe4d55700 (LWP 16625)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff13fc700 (LWP 16626)]
[New Thread 0x7fffefbf9700 (LWP 16627)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff0bfb700 (LWP 16628)]
[Thread 0x7ffff0bfb700 (LWP 16628) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffe4d55700 (LWP 16625) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffefbf9700 (LWP 16627) exited]
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
The program being debugged has been started already.
```

The program has fairly extensive logging, and is certainly not being restarted.  Seems to be running normally.

Not responding to the prompt seems to be fine.  Program continues running.  Responding to the prompt (which should not be possible with the program running) produces that last line of bizarre output, which should be a pre-amble to the first prompt.

Any ideas?  For reference, my full .gdbinit:

```
handle SIGPIPE nostop
set print object on
set print pretty on
set print asm-demangle on
set print symbol on
set pagination off
set history filename ~/.gdb_history
set history save on
set history expansion on
set history size 10000
```

Not sure if cgdb is a factor here or not.

Comment: Do you see these prompts with raw gdb? Are you pressing any keys during cgdb session? (F5 probably)

Comment: @ks1322--Unsure about the first question.  Long-running process, and I'm not sure how to reproduce.  No to the 2nd question.  Detached tmux window, so not possible.